# How to run WearOS app on Fossil Gen 3 Smartwatch

Tags: android, wear-os

I have developed a WearOS app and want to run it on the watch.  I am trying to do it over Wifi Or Bluetooth because the watch does not have a USB port but I can't figure out how to do it.  I have the watch connected to my Samsung Galaxy S9+.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#top_of_page).

To debug your Wear OS app, you can connect your development machine to a watch via [Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#wifi-debugging) or [Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#usb-debugging), as described on this page.

Also, there are resources related to this documentation. you can give it a try.

- [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)
- [Debug Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)
- [Wear OS Design Principles](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/index.html)